# Receiving an error on JavaFX while trying to creating shapes

Tags: java, javafx

I am trying to create a TicTacToe game on javaFX and receiving an error when trying to create tiles.

The method setFill(null) is undefined for the type Rectangle
The method setStroke(Color) is undefined for the type Rectangle

```
private class Square extends StackPane {
    public Square() {
        Rectangle border = new Rectangle(200, 200);
        border.setFill(null);
        border.setStroke(Color.BLACK);
        setAlignment(Pos.CENTER);
        getChildren().addAll(border);

    }
}
```

Comment: Which `Rectangle` did you import?

Comment: @Slaw import com.sun.javafx.geom.Rectangle;

Comment: Aren't those methods for Graphics objects or something?

Comment: There's the problem. You need to import `javafx.scene.shape.Rectangle`.

Comment: @Slaw I've fixed it and that eliminated the .setFill(null) error. Now i have another problem

The method setStroke(Paint) in the type Shape is not applicable for the arguments (Color)

Comment: And what `Color` did you import? Is it `javafx.scene.paint.Color`? As you're using JavaFX make sure to use the JavaFX classes. And make sure they're the correct _public_ classes as well (`com.sun.javafx.geom.Rectangle` is not a public class).

Comment: Also, if your question showed the imports you used it could have been answered without the preceding hassle. See [mcve].

Comment: @Slaw Thank you very much, I have fixed the errors. I will keep that in mind when importing as I am very green when it comes to JavaFX.

Comment: Here's the [Javadoc of JavaFX 12](https://openjfx.io/javadoc/12/) for reference. Note that `StackPane`, which is a descendant of `Region`, provides a [`border`](https://openjfx.io/javadoc/12/javafx.graphics/javafx/scene/layout/Region.html#borderProperty) property.